# Jasper Reports doesn't composite DataBean

Tags: java, jasper-reports, javabeans

I want to map my DataBean(TestModelA) to existing XML, but JasperReports gives me an exception. The problem is that I have custom field (TestModelB) and I have public getters and setters in that class, but jasper does not recognize them. How can i solve this problem?

**TestModelA:**

```
public class TestModelA {
private Long id;
private String label_key;
private TestModelB testModelB;
public TestModelA(Long id, String label_key, TestModelB testModelB) {
    this.id = id;
    this.label_key = label_key;
    this.testModelB = testModelB;
}
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getLabel_key() {
    return label_key;
}
public void setLabel_key(String label_key) {
    this.label_key = label_key;
}
public TestModelB getTestModelB() {
    return testModelB;
}
public void setTestModelB(TestModelB testModelB) {
    this.testModelB = testModelB;
}
}
```

**TestModelB:**

```
public class TestModelB {

private Long owner;
public TestModelB(Long owner) { this.owner = owner;   }

public Long getOwner() {
    return owner;
}

public void setOwner(Long owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
}
}
```

**My XML file:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report3" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="077cd490-b99c-4ed1-ad76-b15714625957">
        <property name="ireport.zoom" value="2.1435888100000016"/>
        <property name="ireport.x" value="94"/>
        <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[SELECT MODULE.ID, MODULE.LABEL_KEY, MODULE.OWNER FROM MODULE]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="id" class="java.lang.Long"/>
        <field name="label_key" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="owner" class="java.lang.Long"/>
        <background>
            <band splitType="Stretch"/>
        </background>
        <columnHeader>
            <band height="21" splitType="Stretch">
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="185" height="20" uuid="68ea9590-9d19-4bc5-9540-d059208b0ce8"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[id]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="185" y="0" width="185" height="20" uuid="325690ac-7218-4000-8ec6-a492d185477a"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[label_key]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="370" y="0" width="185" height="20" uuid="20521e4b-9057-42a9-8adc-10309abc8935"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[owner]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </band>
        </columnHeader>
        <detail>
            <band height="23" splitType="Stretch">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="185" height="20" uuid="11901f0e-b03d-47f8-a8aa-35bab36d26bf"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="185" y="0" width="185" height="20" uuid="b715cb6b-3650-4266-a1cf-552ee35bc08f"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{label_key}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="370" y="0" width="185" height="20" uuid="5c41b534-a74e-4b91-b35d-fcbb88789000"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{owner}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </detail>
    </jasperReport>
```

**I am getting exception:**

```
 Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean : owner
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:123)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getFieldValue(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:96)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource.getFieldValue(JRBeanCollectionDataSource.java:100)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setOldValues(JRFillDataset.java:1330)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1231)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1207)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:1554)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:149)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:909)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:841)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:88)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:653)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:969)
        at net.didorenko.Reporter.creatReport(Reporter.java:99)
        at net.didorenko.Reporter.threeReport(Reporter.java:78)
        at net.didorenko.Reporter.main(Reporter.java:28)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'owner' on class 'class net.didorenko.model.TestModelA'
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1313)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:762)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:837)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:426)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:111)
        ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are passing `TestModelA` class as datasource you need either to create the method in this class or reference the method correctly from jasper report.

**Solution 1 Create method in `TestModelA`**

```
public Long getOwner() {
    return getTestModelB().getOwner(); //Handle NullPointer?
}
```

**Solution 2 Reference correctly in jrxml**

```xml
<field name="testModelB" class="net.didorenko.model.TestModelB"/>
...
<textField>
    <reportElement x="370" y="0" width="185" height="20" uuid="5c41b534-a74e-4b91-b35d-fcbb88789000"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{testModelB}.getOwner()]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: Solution 3: change the report field name from owner to testModelB.owner